# How to click all database buttons generated through php script using a singe button?

Tags: php, html

The problem i've run into is that i have multiple buttons generated through php from data mysql data base and i do not want to manually click them all(it can go over 150). How do i make a button in HTML or PHP to click them all? or How to select the ID of each button (not manually) to include it in the General button?

I have tried `onclick="document.getElementByID('').click()"` atribute on the button that i want to click them all but with no succes

This is the code that i have and the issue:

```
<?php
// server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'testcases';

// connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

//fetching data
// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test1 ORDER BY id"))
{
// display records if there are records to display
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
echo "<table style=\"position:absolute; left:10px; top:80px;\" border ='1px'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
echo "<tbody>"; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><textarea id=\"row->date\">". $row->date ." </textarea></td>";
echo "<td><textarea id=\"row->testcase\">". $row->testcase ."</textarea></td>";
echo "<td><textarea id=\"row->percentage\">". $row->percentage ." </textarea></td>";


echo "<td><a href='temp.php?id=" . $row->id . "'><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" name=\"id\" id=\"$row->id\" >COPY To Temp</button></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
}
echo "</table>";

}
}

// close database connection
$mysqli->close();
?>

<button type="button" style="width:200px" class="pure-button fuller-button1 blue"  onclick="document.getElementByClassName('btn').click();">Copy All</button>
```

The expected result would be to have a table with multiple rows and button generated through php and another button to click them all, but i got stuck at the part where i need to click all the buttons.

Comment: The function is `getElementsByClassName` (note the *plural* "elements"), and it returns a collection that you'd iterate over in a loop.  But the more important question here is... What does clicking any given button here *do*?  If it loads a page then the first one you click is going to cancel the rest of them, so you'd need to re-think what you're actually trying to accomplish.  You're not trying to accomplish "clicking all of the buttons".  You're trying to accomplish some operation or set of operations individually invoked by those buttons.  What is that operation?

Comment: Hey David, every button generated through php inserts a row into my data base. So by my logic(don't know if it's flawed or not) if i have one master button clicking them then i should not be required to press them all manually. I kinda looked into that direction.

Comment: It's a good start, but you're thinking from the wrong direction.  Again, "clicking all the buttons" is not your goal.  "Inserting all the rows" is your goal.  What information does the server need in order to make that happen?  What information does the server *already have*?  It looks like the only data sent to `temp.php` is a single `id` value, which itself comes *from* the server.  So it sounds like all of the information you need is already available to you. If that's the case then all you really should need is either a new page or a way to tell `temp.php` to use all the `id`s in the data.

Comment: Maybe clicking all buttons simultaneously is not the best approach.Why not use checkboxes , a 'select' button  and single submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really wanna do, but first of all it's a really strange thing to put a button into a link: if you want a like you can add a span child styled like a button and if you really want a button just listen to click events on it.

Another thing would be that you could use form + checkboxes so that your button can make a single action by submitting form (and this single action/HTTP query will be exploded in N actions (loop) server-side)

If you really would like to do this like you do, using ID property is not wrong but it doesn't help readability nor CSS selection, I would use `data-*` attributes.

So, now you want a simple answer ;)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].click(); // or anything you want
}
```

If you wanna get `id` properties you can do:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var ids = [];
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    ids.push(elements[i].id);
}
```

If you plan to use jQuery:

```
var ids = [];
$(".btn").each(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    ids.push($button.attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: @Azazel since I'm still "New contributor" with less than 50 contribs I cannot answer you directly in the good section but I think that it can be useful for you and other readers: if the Fabricio solution seems to be useless it's simply because his scripts tries to get the clicked button id ... and this button has no id attribute.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="copyBtn()">Copy</button>
```

and using jQuery

```
function copyBtn(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Hey Fabricio, unfortunatelly, that function does not work, i got no error message but i got no result either, honestly i don't know what it is the cause for that :(.